# Singleton created with enum type, problems with threads safety

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, thread-safety, concurrentmodification

Good day, I have created Singleton :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public enum Singleton {
    FIRST_INSTANCE;

    String[] scrabbleLetters = {
            "a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
            "c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d",
    };

    private LinkedList<String> letterList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(scrabbleLetters));

    private Object lock = new Object();

    private Singleton() {
        Collections.shuffle(letterList);
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return FIRST_INSTANCE;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getLetterList() {
        synchronized (lock) {

        return FIRST_INSTANCE.letterList;
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getTiles(int howManyTiles) {
        synchronized (lock) {

        LinkedList<String> tilesToSend = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<= howManyTiles; i++) {
            tilesToSend.add(FIRST_INSTANCE.letterList.remove(0));
        }
        return tilesToSend;

        }
    }

}
```

and I have tested it on threads safety with this example :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ScrabbleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable getTiles = () -> {

            System.out.println("In thread : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Singleton newInstance = Singleton.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Instance ID: " + System.identityHashCode(newInstance));
            System.out.println(newInstance.getLetterList());

            LinkedList<String> playerOneTiles = newInstance.getTiles(7);
            System.out.println("Player : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + playerOneTiles);
            System.out.println("Got Tiles for " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        };

        new Thread(getTiles, "First").start();
        new Thread(getTiles, "Second").start();
    }
}
```

After executing it 10 times , I was sure that there is no problem, but when I run it last time I received this stack trace :

```
In thread : Second
In thread : First
Instance ID: 1380197535
Instance ID: 1380197535
[d, d, b, c, b, b, a, d, c, d, a, d, c, a, a, d, c, a, a, b, d, b, b, a, b, c, a, d, c, a, c, b, c, c, b, d, d]
Player : First[d, d, b, c, b, b, a, d]
Got Tiles for First
Exception in thread "Second" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    at ScrabbleTest.lambda$0(ScrabbleTest.java:10)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This exception happens quit rarely, about 1 time for 20 executions.
I have found that ConcurrentModificationException may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible. In the code I have a lock that should prevent this situations, there is the same lock for changing and retrieving the list for  synchronized blocks. I don't even imagine why this happens.

Comment: Your code is not thread safe. Period. The problem occurs with `System.out.println(newInstance.getLetterList());` which is not protected by any synchronized block.

Comment: Method `getLetterList()` has a synchronized block, isn't it enough?

Comment: No, the problem happens **after** the list has been returned (and the synchronized block has been exited), you either need to copy the list, or you need to convert the list to string in a synchronized block and print that instead. However your approach is fraught with a lot of other problems that you should fix instead. Ask yourself why you even use a singleton here. What if you want to do multiple games in the same run, etc, etc. This solution isn't the right one, and that is the problem you should address instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CME` doesn't have as much to do with concurrency as the name might make you think. The most common occurrence for `CME` is in a single threaded context. In this case however, the threading is involved too.

Your problem comes from `tilesToSend.add(FIRST_INSTANCE.letterList.remove(0));` in which you're modifying the `letterList`, but it's being iterated at the same time by `println`. Synchronization won't help here, since you'd have to synchronize a lot larger blocks than what is realistically possible.

Easy solution here is to return a copy of the list in `getLetterList()` like

```
return new LinkedList<>(FIRST_INSTANCE.letterList);
```

This way the original list can be modified by `remove()` while `println` is iterating the copy.